# Search String in file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to count the number of times a specific string appears into a file.

This is the code I am using:

```
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String nextToken = scanner.next();
            if (nextToken.equalsIgnoreCase(wordidnamee1))
                count++;
        }
```

This code only counts the number of time the string appears 'clean', but if it is attached to another word or followed by a colon it is not counted.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What about case where you want to find `aa` and string is `aaaa`? How many times `aa` appears in it: 2 or 3 (or maybe 1)?

Comment: This is **too-broad**, what you are asking for is a complete indexing engine with fuzzy logic on what constitutes a *word*.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: @Pshemo Considering the range of words to be found, I do not need to study such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Use contains()

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String nextToken = scanner.next();
    if (nextToken.contains(wordidnamee1))
        count++;
}
```

**For Non Case Sensitive match:**

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String nextToken = scanner.next();
        if (nextToken.toLowerCase().contains(wordidnamee1.toLowerCase()))
            count++;
    }
```